# In Highchart R package how to display multiple line charts but Starting with only 2 lines

Tags: r, highcharts

I want to plot a highchart plot with 5 countries.

But I would like to start the chart with only "Chile" and "Argentina" lines.
And then I would let the use add the others countries interactively by clicking on the others countries legends.

Is it possible?

```
library(highcharter)
library(gapminder)


gapminder %>%  filter(country == c("Chile","Argentina","Peru","Brazil","Portugal")) %>%
  hchart("line",
        hcaes(x = year, y = pop, group = country))
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to load the countries in two steps, one marked `visible = FALSE`.

Unfortunately, this makes the groups out of alphabetical order, so it would take some manual work with more layers to control both the ordering and the initial visibility.

```
gap_vis <- subset(gapminder, country %in% c("Chile","Argentina"))
gap_hid <- subset(gapminder, country %in% c("Peru","Brazil","Portugal"))
  
hchart(gap_vis, "line", hcaes(x = year, y = pop, group = country)) %>%
hc_add_series(gap_hid, "line", hcaes(x = year, y = pop, group = country), 
              visible = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to only set `visible: false` for the proper series. Example in pure JS:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Chile',
    data: [...]
  }, {
    name: 'Argentina',
    data: [...]
  }, {
    name: 'Peru',
    data: [...],
    visible: false
  }, {
    name: 'Brazil',
    data: [...],
    visible: false
  }, {
    name: 'Portugal',
    data: [...],
    visible: false
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4ebnj0Lq/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.visible